# Отразить персонажа взависимости от направления в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Недавно стал изучать Unity. Вроде бы всё нормально, но после добавления анимаций персонаж перестал отражаться в левую сторону, а до работал способ с flipX. Я посмотрел довольно много способов, но ни один мне не подошёл. Заранее спасибо! Если понадобится код, до попросите.

Comment: Сделай анимацию движения в левую сторону, вместо flipX. Добавь параметр направления в контроллер, в зависимости от того, отрицательное значение или положительное воспроизводи нужную анимацию

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!